# How to share resources between several threads?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, boto3

I'm writing a script that should retrieve file data from S3 storage in parallel. I cannot do that with a simple Pool object from multiprocessing module, because then I get the error that boto3. Resource object cannot be pickled.

I see why, and I implemented a solution which uses Pool, but target function does not use shared Resource and instead creates new Resource within each thread. But I found that to be extremely inefficient to the extent that even sequential processing would be faster.

I know that Pool has an option to set the number of workers which are used, but is there any way to create several instances of Resource and "asssign" them to those workers so I would not have to create a new instance for each item to be processed?

Code:

```
class Client:

    def __init__(self, url, access_key, secret_key):
        self.url = url
        self.access_key = access_key
        self.secret_key = secret_key

    def get_resource(self):
        return boto3.resource('s3',
                              endpoint_url=self.url,
                              aws_access_key_id=self.access_key,
                              aws_secret_access_key=self.secret_key)

    def get_data_for_object(self, key):
        data = []
        resource = self.get_resource()
        for line in resource.Object(bucket_name='bucket_name', key=key).get()['Body'].iter_lines():
            data.append(json.loads(line))
        return data

    def get_data_for_minute(self, minute):
        keys = [...] # object keys in S3 storage
        pool = Pool()
        data = pool.imap(self.get_data_for_object, keys)
        flat_data = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(data))
        return flat_data
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Thanks, code added.

Comment: You should create the Resource objects in a loop outside the method that is submitted to the Pool.

Comment: I get that, but how do I pass those objects to the method? Because I cannot make them Clients attribute, that way I would get the error I mentioned above.

Comment: You mentioned threads in the title but you are using multiprocessing in the code. Those are very different things. With multiprocessing you don't have much choice but to recreate the Resource object in their own processes.